# Get xhr requests using Selenium-wire and undetected-chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I'm following the code below, but couldn't get the XHR requests. Code from [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/). Anyway to fix this?

```py
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc

chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()

driver = uc.Chrome(
    options=chrome_options,
    seleniumwire_options={}
)

r = driver.requests
```

```
AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no attribute 'requests'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade `selenium-wire` to `4.6.1` or above

```
pip install selenium-wire --upgrade
```

You can also avoid upgrading with the following code:

```py
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.some-anti-bot-site.com")
    r = driver.requests
```

More info in [here](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/517)